# Inpainting missing curved segment in an image

Tags: java, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision, bezier

I have few images (very low resolution), but due to the inconsistency in data collection, the images sometimes have a missing segment which can be identified by checking for horizontal lines from bottom (atleast that is what I do). I want to fix the missing segment with a reasonable curve in real-time.  For example-
[image][image]
Unfortunately, I cannot upload the image in it's actual size, but if you want to experiment you can comment and then I will try to send few data as numpy arrays.

**What have I tried?**
I have tried fixing the segments using Bezier curves. My Idea was to take the extremes of the horizontal segment as P<sub>0</sub> and P<sub>3</sub> and then calculate the intersection point P<sub>1</sub> as shown in my code below:

```
public static Coordinate<Integer> pointofIntersection(List<Coordinate<Integer>> line1, List<Coordinate<Integer>> line2) {
        var m1 = (line1.get(1).row - line1.get(0).row) / (line1.get(1).col - line1.get(0).col);
        var m2 = (line2.get(1).row - line2.get(0).row) / (line2.get(1).col - line2.get(0).col);
        var c1 = line1.get(0).row - m1 * line1.get(0).col;
        var c2 = line2.get(0).row - m2 * line2.get(0).col;
        m2 = m2==0?-1:m2;
        m1 = m1==0?1:m1;
        var slope_diff = (m1 - m2)==0?1:(m1-m2);
        var x = (c2 - c1) / slope_diff;
        var y = m1 * x + c1;
        var slope_ratio = Math.abs((float)m1/(float)m2)>1?Math.pow(Math.abs((float)m1/(float)m2),0.5):Math.pow(Math.abs((float)m1/(float)m2),2);
        x = (int) (x/ slope_ratio);

        return new Coordinate<Integer>(y, x);
}
```

Finally after getting P<sub>1</sub>, I estimate the fourth control point P<sub>2</sub> for Bezier curve as the center point of the line joining P<sub>3</sub> and P<sub>1</sub> and then I put P<sub>2</sub>.y = P<sub>1</sub>.y
After Calculating the four control points, I calculate the Bezier curve as follows:

```
public List<Coordinate<Integer>> generateBezierPath4Points(ArrayList<Coordinate<Integer>> controlPoints, int segments) {
    ArrayList<Coordinate<Integer>> pointsForReturn = new ArrayList<Coordinate<Integer>>();

    float t = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
        Coordinate p = new Coordinate(-1,-1);
        var x = ((1-t)*(1-t)*(1-t)* controlPoints.get(0).col)+ (3*(1-t)*(1-t)*t*controlPoints.get(1).col) + (3*(1-t)*t*t*controlPoints.get(2).col) + (t*t*t*controlPoints.get(3).col);
        var y = ((1-t)*(1-t)*(1-t)* controlPoints.get(0).row)+ (3*(1-t)*(1-t)*t*controlPoints.get(1).row) + (3*(1-t)*t*t*controlPoints.get(2).row) + (t*t*t*controlPoints.get(3).row);
        Double r = Math.ceil(y);
        Double c = Math.ceil(x);
        p.row = r.intValue();
        p.col = c.intValue();
        t += 1.0f / segments;
        pointsForReturn.add(p);
    }
    return pointsForReturn;
}
```

**My Results**
[image]  [image]

**What do I expect?**
As you can clearly see that my estimations are sometimes more convex than expected. I want to fill the missing segment such that it appears more natural as I have tried to plot with inkscape (filled in red), where I can visually control the curve. see below:
[image]

Comment: Can you expand the code a little by turning this into a [mcve]? (with the data loading and processing replaced by just "loading in the image file you're showing" which should only be a few lines of code).

Answer (score 2):

If you use a quadratic or cubic Bezier, you can rely on the fact that the control point(s) *define(s)* the tangent at the start and end points.

Find your "cutoff" row, and then walk up the shape (with whatever visual processing library you're already using) on the left and right a little to pick the curve's start and end points. The first control point then lies somewhere on a line from the start point along the contour, with the same being true for the end point:

[image]

The simplest Bezier-based infill would be a quadratic curve, with the single control point at the intersection of those two lines. If you don't have quadratic primitives but you do have cubic primitives, you can get the exact same curve by creating control points by linear interpolation of the start+intersection and intersection+end pairs (See the second paragraph in https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#reordering).

Or you could reconstruct the "perfect" cubic by reversing de Casteljau's procedure (see https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#abc) but I strongly doubt that's worth the effort.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for you answer, I had a further question though. You said I can walk along the contour from the cut-off, but can this be made somehow deterministic, because I would like to generate same output for the same shape. Is there some loss/ cost I can calculate so the start and end points are fixed? 
The location of the start and end point influence the intersection a lot, which I had been calculating till now, then I usually add some additional constraints to bring the intersection closer but it is very co-incidental.

Comment: Depends on what kind of data you're working with, and in which language: you talked about numpy arrays, suggesting Python, but the code you're showing looks like Java, so... "if you can describe the exact data format you're using, and the tech stack(s) you're tied to in your post" then there's probably something more concrete to talk about =)

Comment: Hi @Mike, I am working with java and not using any image processing library, I am using 2d arrays in java to process this data. I just said of sending numpy arrays because, I thought python is what most people use.

Comment: people use _a lot_ of things, probably a good idea to at least tag your post with java, and maybe talk about the data your code uses right now. Because even if someone's going to say "instead of that, do this: ..." we need to know your current setup before we recommend solutions.

Comment: I have already mentioned my current steps, which is to take two extremas as control point p0 and p3 and find the third control point as the intersection of the lines drawn from the extremas and extremas.y-4. The first intersection point is p1, then I again find the mid point of line joining p1 and p3 to get  the final control point p2. Additionally, I am open to suggestions in any language, I just want to understand how can I optimize the location of my control points such that the curve fits better. 
Should I use something else other than Bezier curves?

Comment: I don't mean "the code for drawing the infill", I mean the code that shows off the entire process. If you read through the official ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) guidelines you'll notice it talks about making sure you have as complete as possible code (with anything that be omitted removed, and anything that isn't part of the problem but required to show it off hardcoded to minimal form). Because that lets people copy your code, make it work, and then post that now-working-code in the answer they write.